# C Calculator using parameters doesn't output anything

Tags: c, calculator, postfix-notation

heres the code (sorry if theres crap formatting, trying to copy out of console is dumb (vim)):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printhelp(){
    printf("\nhelp\n");     /* TODO make this more accurate */
}

int numstack[32];
char numpointer = 0;

char pushNum(int in){
    if(numpointer < 31)
        numstack[numpointer++] = in;
   else return 1;
   return 0; 
}

int popNum(){
    printf("%i", numstack[numpointer]);
    if(numpointer)
        return numstack[numpointer--];
    else return -1;
}
void handleOp(char op){
    switch(op){
        case '+':
            pushNum(popNum + popNum);
            break;
        case '-':
            pushNum(popNum - popNum);
            break;
        case '*':
            pushNum(popNum * popNum);
            break;
        case '/':
            pushNum(popNum / popNum);
            break;
    }
}

/* MAIN */
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    switch(argc){
     case 1:
            printhelp();
            return 0;
      case 2:
            if(argv[1][0] == '-'){
                if(argv[1][1] == 'h')
                    printhelp();
                return 0;
            }
    }
    int args = 1;
    int argtot = argc;
    int num;
    while(args <= argtot){
        num = atoi(argv[args]);
        if(num > 48)
            pushNum(atoi(argv[args]));
       handleOp(argv[args++][0]);
    }
    printf("total: %i", popNum());
    return 0;
}
```

i got a few warnings to do with type casting, mostly between pointer and int. I've fixed all those now but the final printf doesn't output anything now, and when it did all it gave me was zeros and my numstack appears to be filled with junk, but i don't understand why; even explicitly initialising it to 32 0s doesn't change that. the end goal is for something like:

> > input
>
> calc 2 3 + 4 *
>
> > output
>
> 20

where input can be any length [reverse polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) mathematical expression, and it will solve it. right now i only care about + - * / but would like to add powers modulus etc eventually, and some assembly for practice. also i realise i have inconsistent capitalisation with some of my variables and probably a few other bad habits, im working to fix those

(im using tcc on win10 if that helps)

Comment: `pushNum(popNum + popNum);` is wrong. `popNum` is a function, which becomes a pointer to the function in this expression, and you cannot add pointers to functions. You want the value returned from calling `popNum` here, which would be `popNum()`. The compiler almost certainly gave you an error message about this.

Comment: Include `<stdlib.h>` to declare `atoi`.

Comment: `num = atoi(argv[args]);` and `if(num > 48)`. Rethink what you are doing there. How do you test if a string contains only digit characters? What are the digit characters? Why would you use `48` instead of `'0'`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil i completely missed that thanks! i wouldve thought tcc would say something but surprisingly not at all. it complained about pointer conversion around the call to handleOp but never there. Ill see if i can bring that up to the devs

Comment: `handleOp(argv[args++][0]);` comes immediately after pushing a number. But how do you know the argument after a number is an operator? In the example you give, it is not: In “2 3 + 4 *”, the argument after “2” is a number, not an operator.

Comment: i implemented your first 3 comments and after that the results it gave were all the first parameter with a leading 0; added an else into the shorthand if at the call to handleOp and now the program just freezes. ill look closely at it again to see if i spot something but nothing springs to mind

Comment: The `*` on the command line might expand to a list of all file names, and most of those might map to zero when converted by `atoi()`.

Comment: i wouldve thought it shouldnt, although the same issues occur with input of e.g. "calc 2 + 3", so there's something else somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You have a large number of problems made much more difficult to spot due to the lack of any sane spacing in your code. Don't put multiple expressions on the same line, you are not getting paid by the number of lines you save, and DO space your code better, it makes your code much more readable (especially for those with older eyes...). For example there is no reason for not a single space in:

```
pushNum(atoi(argv[args]));
```

Add validations at each step in your code and give all functions that can either succeed or fail a meaningful return type that can indicate success or failure. For example, what if the character passed to `void handleOp(int op)`<sup>**[1]**</sup> is `'z'` and not one of the operators? Better as:

```
int handleOp(int op)
{
    switch(op){
        ...
        default: 
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Now on to the fundamental logic errors in your code. In `popNum()` you `return numstack[numpointer--];` This is wrong. You must decrement `numpointer` BEFORE using it as an index. Currently your code might as well be `return numstack[numpointer];` as that is what your expression evaluates to. In order to be correct, you would need to either use the prefix increment `return numstack[--numpointer];`, or better simply:

```
int popNum()
{
    if (numpointer--)   /* must decrement numpointer BEFORE return */
        return numstack[numpointer];

    return -1;
}
```

Next, your code should not compile as you are trying to, e.g. `pushNum(popNum + popNum);` There `popNum` is the *function pointer* NOT the evaluated return of `popNum()`. Your `handleOp()` function should instead use the return of the function itself, e.g.

```
int handleOp(int op)
{
    switch(op){
        case '+':
            pushNum(popNum() + popNum());  /* note the '()' making the function call */
            break;
        ...
```

Additionally, thereafter, your *division* is actually evaluated as `divisor / dividend` (reversed) instead it should be `dividend / divisor`, to fix the issue you can use:

```
        case '/':
            {
                int a = popNum(), b = popNum();
                pushNum (b / a);
                break;
            }
```

In `main()`, you must use `while (args < argtot)` NOT `while (args <= argtot)`. Recall, `argv[argc]` is a `NULL` pointer.

Beyond that, never use `atoi` in code other than for testing. It provides **ZERO** ability to evaluate whether the conversion succeeded or failed. You could have `atoi("dog")` and it still wouldn't tell you things had gone wrong, and all you know is you got `0` from it. Instead, always use the `strtoX` family of functions (e.g. `strtol, strtoul, strtod, etc..`) There you have the ability to fully validate every conversion.

Those were the major problems, though there are certainly more. Resolving those issues allows it to work correctly for your example and the division now works as well. Putting those fixes together you could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>

void printhelp()    /* you are not paid on the no. of lines you save */
{
    printf("\nhelp\n");     /* TODO make this more accurate */
}

int numstack[32];       /* avoid the use of global variables */
int numpointer = 0;

char pushNum(int in)
{
    if (numpointer < 31) {
        numstack[numpointer++] = in;
        return 0; 
    }

    return 1;
}

int popNum()
{
    if (numpointer--)   /* must decrement numpointer BEFORE return */
        return numstack[numpointer];

    return -1;
}

int handleOp(int op)
{
    switch(op){
        case '+':
            pushNum(popNum() + popNum());
            break;
        case '-':
            pushNum(popNum() - popNum());
            break;
        case '*':
            pushNum(popNum() * popNum());
            break;
        case '/':
            {
                int a = popNum(), b = popNum();
                pushNum (b / a);
                break;
            }
        default: 
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

/* MAIN */
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int args = 1;       /* declares vars at beginning of scope for those */
    int argtot = argc;  /* pour souls still stuck with C89 compilers */
    int num;

    switch (argc) {
    case 1:
            printhelp();
            return 0;
    case 2:
            if (argv[1][0] == '-') {
                if(argv[1][1] == 'h')
                    printhelp();
                return 0;
            }
    }

    while (args < argtot) {
        if (isdigit (*argv[args])) {                /* validate digit */
            char *endptr = NULL;
            num = strtol (argv[args], &endptr, 0);  /* never use atoi */
            if (endptr == argv[args]) { /* atoi provides ZERO validation */
                fputs ("error: no digits converted.\n", stderr);
                return 1;
            }
            else if (errno) {
                fputs ("error: over/underflow occured.\n", stderr);
                return 1;
            }
            else if (num < 0 || INT_MAX < num) {
                fputs ("error: value negative or exceeds INT_MAX.\n", stderr);
                return 1;
            }
            pushNum (num);
        }
        else {
            if (!handleOp (*argv[args])) {
                fputs ("error: unrecognized OP.\n", stderr);
                return 1;
            }
        }
        args++;
    }

    printf("total: %d\n", popNum());

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** the opening `'{'` following a function name generally goes on the next line (except for `main() {` where a space can precede it))

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/calcpostfix 2 3 + 4 '*'
total: 20
```

With division:

```
$ ./bin/calcpostfix 2 3 + 4 '*' 5 '*' 10 /
total: 10
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

**Footnotes:**

**1)** While not an error, C generally avoids the use of `camelCase` or `MixedCase` variable and function names in favor of all *lower-case* while reserving *upper-case* names for use with macros and constants. It is a matter of style -- so it is completely up to you, but failing to follow it can lead to the wrong first impression in some circles. See e.g. [**NASA - C Style Guide, 1994**](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/dts/pm/Papers/nasa-c-style.pdf) (still good)